# How to chain Python Popen calls together correctly?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

This is turning out not to be as simple as I thought it should be.  What I am trying to do is chain a few commands using `Popen` by setting the `stdin` of the commands to the `stdout` of the previous command (or `PIPE` for the first `stdin`).  Additionally I set the `stderr`s of the commands to `open`-ed files.

What I am seeing is that basically this doesn't work at all until I `close` the `stdin` of the first command.  I am expecting the processes to communicate down the pipe chain when I write to the first command's `stdin` but nothing gets written to the second command until I close the first command's `stdin`.  Similarly, none of the `stderr` files are actually written to until I close the first command's `stdin`.

Consider the following examples:

`./cat.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys, datetime

def log(msg, file):
   file.write(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + ': ' + msg + '\n')

log('starting now', sys.stdout)
log('rofl', sys.stderr)

for input_line in iter(sys.stdin.readline, ''):
   input_line = input_line.rstrip('\n')

   log(input_line, sys.stdout)
   log('lol ' + input_line, sys.stderr)

log('ending now', sys.stdout)
```

and

`./basic.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys, subprocess

subproc = []

length = 4
for i in range(0, length):
   if i == 0:
      subproc.append(subprocess.Popen('./cat.py', bufsize=0, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=open(str(i) + '.stderr', 'w')))
   elif i == length - 1:
      subproc.append(subprocess.Popen('./cat.py', bufsize=0, stdin=subproc[-1].stdout, stdout=open(str(i) + '.stdout', 'w'), stderr=open(str(i) + '.stderr', 'w')))
   else:
      subproc.append(subprocess.Popen('./cat.py', bufsize=0, stdin=subproc[-1].stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=open(str(i) + '.stderr', 'w')))

for input_line in iter(sys.stdin.readline, ''):
   input_line = input_line.rstrip('\n')

   subproc[0].stdin.write((input_line + '\n').encode())
```

This will start a 4-process `Popen` chain and write the `stderr`s to `0.stderr`, `1.stderr`, etc. and write the final `stdout` to `3.stdout`.  Output lines are timestamped so you can easily verify when a specific subprocess received input.  Consider these outputs from a basic test I did waiting a few seconds between inputs.

`0.stderr`

```
2018-03-07 16:18:48.316847: rofl
2018-03-07 16:18:51.815376: lol hello 1
2018-03-07 16:18:55.561168: lol hello 2
2018-03-07 16:18:59.204273: lol hello 3
```

`1.stderr`

```
2018-03-07 16:18:48.320991: rofl
2018-03-07 16:19:01.888496: lol 2018-03-07 16:18:48.316825: starting now
2018-03-07 16:19:01.888508: lol 2018-03-07 16:18:51.815345: hello 1
2018-03-07 16:19:01.888515: lol 2018-03-07 16:18:55.561136: hello 2
2018-03-07 16:19:01.888523: lol 2018-03-07 16:18:59.204241: hello 3
2018-03-07 16:19:01.888531: lol 2018-03-07 16:19:01.886950: ending now
```

`3.stdout`

```
2018-03-07 16:18:48.323203: starting now
2018-03-07 16:19:01.899180: 2018-03-07 16:18:48.323766: starting now
2018-03-07 16:19:01.899208: 2018-03-07 16:19:01.895778: 2018-03-07 16:18:48.320973: starting now
2018-03-07 16:19:01.899216: 2018-03-07 16:19:01.895804: 2018-03-07 16:19:01.888476: 2018-03-07 16:18:48.316825: starting now
2018-03-07 16:19:01.899224: 2018-03-07 16:19:01.895813: 2018-03-07 16:19:01.888504: 2018-03-07 16:18:51.815345: hello 1
2018-03-07 16:19:01.899233: 2018-03-07 16:19:01.895820: 2018-03-07 16:19:01.888512: 2018-03-07 16:18:55.561136: hello 2
2018-03-07 16:19:01.899240: 2018-03-07 16:19:01.895829: 2018-03-07 16:19:01.888519: 2018-03-07 16:18:59.204241: hello 3
2018-03-07 16:19:01.899247: 2018-03-07 16:19:01.895836: 2018-03-07 16:19:01.888527: 2018-03-07 16:19:01.886950: ending now
2018-03-07 16:19:01.899254: 2018-03-07 16:19:01.895844: 2018-03-07 16:19:01.892480: ending now
2018-03-07 16:19:01.899262: 2018-03-07 16:19:01.895860: ending now
2018-03-07 16:19:01.899277: ending now
```

As you can see, the first subprocess gets my `write`s in real-time but then the chain stalls until I close the first subprocess's `stdin`.  This is despite me using `bufsize=0` for all `Popen` calls.  (Without using `0` then not even the first subprocess received any of my `write`s until after closing `stdin`.)

Is what I'm trying to do possible?  What is the correct way to do this?

`communicate` will not work in my case, because that function closes `stdin`.  I need to keep `stdin` open the whole while to process additional incoming data.  I need to keep the first `stdin` open to receive additional input while the output from the command is sent down the pipe chain, handled by the next command and sent further down the pipe chain.

Any suggestions?

I am using Python 3.4.3.

Thank you,

Comment: Have you tried calling `stdin.flush()` after you write to the stream?

Comment: I had a `.flush()` in place on the first `stdin` for many of the tests I did.  But where it was missing was in the subprocesses.  Adding a `.flush()` in `cat.py` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transferring data between processes is expensive (relative to many simple computations within a process).  The kernel amortizes the cost by waiting until a "significant" amount of data is pending—or until the pipe is closed, since obviously there's no point waiting for more data then.  This happens between *each* pair of processes.  Your `bufsize=0` affects only writes *within* the parent process, which is why it works only for feeding the first stage of the pipeline.

Some programs provide options to control their output buffering (*i.e.*, they can ask the kernel to transfer data early): Python itself offers `python -u`.  (If it's *your* Python program, use `flush()` like g.d.d.c suggested in *each* process.)  Otherwise, there is a (mostly) generic utility [`unbuffer`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unbuffer) that might get you immediate responses.

Comment: the key words in this answer were `each process`.  That was my problem, my `cat.py` test script was not flushing their output buffers.  So my subprocess creation/management code was correct, it was the subprocesses themselves that were incorrect.  Adding a `.flush()` after every write in `cat.py` made the whole thing work exactly like I was expecting.  What made me realize this was trying to convert to building a long shell command and using `shell=True` but when that had the same exact results, I knew I needed to explicitly flush the subprocess buffers.  Python, always a pleasure.  Thanks!!!!

Comment: @rogeralston: It’s not Python doing this: all languages buffer by default unless writing directly to a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys, subprocess

length = 4
stdin = sys.stdin
stdout = subprocess.PIPE
command = ['python3', './cat.py']

for i in range(length):
    if i == length - 1:
        stdout = open('stdout', 'w')
    stderr = open('{}.stderr'.format(i), 'w')
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=stdin, stdout=stdout, stderr=stderr)
    stdin = process.stdout

process.communicate()
```

## Notes

- I am running on Linux and running just `'./cat.py'` does not work for me, I have to use `['python3', './cat.py']`
- My approach works by chaining one process' `stdout` to the next one's `stdin`
- `stdout` is `subprocess.PIPE`, except for the last one, which is a file
- Call `communicate()` on the last process will set the pipe chain in action

Have a good day.

Comment: This does not work because I need to keep `stdin` open to receive input continuously while subprocesses further down the chain handle the input to date.  The missing piece from my example was flushing the output buffers in the subprocesses' code.  On Linux `./cat.py` will work if you have permission to execute the file (and your Python 3 binary is at `/usr/bin/python3`).